# What are the attributes of a new window, if opened by a window.open function?

Tags: javascript

If I add this code between a `<script>` and a `</script>`:

```
function test()
{
    var newWindow = window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/", "a", "width = 600,height = 400");
    document.write(newWindow.location.href);
    document.write(newWindow.innerWidth);
}
test();
```

And the output is "about:blank" and 0, though I think it should be "https://stackoverflow.com/" and 600.
I am so confused about this and waiting for a explanation.

AND: if I do want to get the URL of the new window, how should I do?
MANY THANKS.

Comment: Most likely a timing issue. Opening the new window doesn’t happen “immediately”, but that task is handed off to the browser, and your script continues without waiting for the popup to be fully instantiated & loaded. _“if I do want to get the URL of the new window, how should I do?”_ – your script just opened the window, so you should already know.

Comment: Also bear in mind that your options for accessing anything about the new window will be limited if it's loading something from a different domain.

Comment: Sounds like a very roundabout way to get the URL. If you're executing `window.open()` don't you already have access to the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture these values asynchronously if you wait on the `load` event:

```
var newWindow = window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', 'a', 'width=600,height=400')
newWindow.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log(newWindow.location.href);
    console.log(newWindow.innerWidth);
});
```

However, as James Thorpe points out, this will only work if the new window is in the same domain as the page where the script is running, and this happens asynchronously, so whatever you're trying to accomplish by using `document.write()` might not work.